# Use Keycloak and JWT Statelessly in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I need to use Keycloak and prefer to use stateless JWT tokens with my Spring Boot application. I can get it to run OK with sessions, but when converting this I need help

- Forcing Spring Boot Security to check for logins
- Allow a /logout URL (that goes to Keycloak)

My code "runs", but when I hit the initial page, I'm seeing log messages that seem to suggest it did not detect any sign of being logged in. When this happens, I'd like to force Spring Boot to redirect to the login page just like it would have had this been a stateful application.

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet: Failed to complete request: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken.getName()" because "authenticationToken" is null
org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper: Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken.getName()" because "authenticationToken" is null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken.getName()" because "authenticationToken" is null
```

Here's my HttpSecurity snippet:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
        .csrf()
//      .disable().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/sso/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/css/**","/contact-us","/actuator/**","/isalive/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/myfirstpage",true)
        .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

    }
```

I know I'm missing something, but I thought Keycloak provided a lot of these things OOTB. The initial URL is /. I had hoped the .authenticated() would force it to authenticate against all patterns not permitted, but I'm likely wrong. What am I missing?

Please note, the internet is awash with examples of Spring Boot + Keycloak (a few are even good). It also has a lot of Spring Boot + OAuth + Stateless JWT. It does not have (that I can tell) a lot of Spring Boot + Keycloak + Stateless JWT. I got the little that I could find from this JHipster repo, but I feel like I'm missing some grand magical step.

Answer (score 1):

In your conf, `oauth2Login` is consistent with neither `oauth2ResourceServer` nor your wish to authorize requests with JWTs.

Login and logout are the responsibility of clients, not resource servers. It is also the responsibility of clients to obtain and store tokens: **you must be a client to get a JWT from an authorization server**.

Only ressource servers can be stateless (without session). Spring clients need session during authorization code flow, and to store tokens.

Only requests between a client and a resource server are authorized with an access token (requests to a clients are authorized with sessions).

**Resource-server** should return 401 (unauthorized) when authentication is missing or invalid (expired, wrong issuer, etc.) and **client** should handle redirection to **authorization-server** for login.

REST APIs should be configured as resource servers: stateless, requests authorized with Bearer access tokens but without login or logout.

OAuth2 resource servers are queried by OAuth2 clients which handle login, logout, tokens storage and requests authorization with Bearer access tokens. Sample of such clients:

- dev tools like Postman
- Spring application with server side rendered templates (Thymeleaf, JSF, etc.)
- a **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend. `spring-cloud-gateway` can be configured as BFF: as an OAuth2 client with login, logout and `TokenRelay=` filter to replace session cookie with an access token before forwarding a request from a front-end to a resource server.
- Javascript based application (Angular, React, Vue, etc.) configured as a public OAuth2 client with a lib like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client), but this is not recommended anymore in favor of the BFF pattern where confidential clients are used and tokens are hidden from the Javascript (requests between browsers and the BFF secured with sessions).

Last, an application can be both a resource server and a client with OAuth2 login. This is the case for instance in apps exposing publicly both a REST API authorized with JWTs and Thymeleaf pages. But in that case, you should define two distinct security filter-chains: a client one with sessions and oauth2Login for Thymeleaf controllers and a stateless resource server one with JWT decoder for REST controllers.

For more OAuth2 background and spring applications configuration (including BFF and application being both resource server and client with login), refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials).

Answer (score -1):

You will need spring-security and keycloak-adapters
This guid has full explanation how to setup and secure it

https://keepgrowing.in/java/springboot/keycloak-with-spring-boot-1-configure-spring-security-with-keycloak/

Comment: Do not use Keycloak adapter for spring, it is deprecated: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187

Comment: @ch4mp I'll try this when I get back from holiday. While it looks like a well thought out answer, I'm concerned with my app directly redirecting the caller if unauthorized. Had this not been a stateless jwt, Spring Security and/or Keycloak would handle this. I haven't fully digested your response yet so I haven't yet accepted it though the idea of me checking for a token with every request seems to negate the utility of the underlaying frameworks.

Comment: I forgot to add my application is a server side Thyme Leaf application.

Comment: @Woodsman your Thymeleaf app is an [OAuth2 client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html). As stated in my answer, it is client role to redirect unauthorized users to authorization-server.

Comment: Ok, so how to I explicitly check for the token presence, fetch the right redirect URL and then send that back to the client explicitly? I don't know why, because I'm doing stateless JWT, I have to do that. Again, the client does it, but with the help of the framework.

Comment: Request to Thymeleaf pages won't be authorized with a JWT. It will be with a session and there is nothing you can do about that: your browser can't fetch and store JWTs by itself. Only requests from Thymeleaf controller to a REST API (when ModelAndView is built) can be authorized with JWTs, provided that the Thymeleaf application is configured as an OAuth2 client and the REST API as an OAuth2 resource server with JWT decoder. Also, I completely refreshed my answer, trying to be clearer.